# Command Prompt Target wrong

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe

I have recently tried to fix my old PC for my friend to use. I was trying to open up CMD but when I click on it or even try and run as administration it never comes up. When I got to properties this is what shows up

[image: cmd properties screenshot]

I have tired to go to my PC, click on the disk, then click on Windows, then System32, and then I can't find cmd like on other videos

Comment: Can you run PowerShell?  You have to tell us exactly what you tried to fix this.  Give us specifics about the system.

Comment: Reinstall Windows

Comment: I would like to say thank you for the responses. This is my first post and thank you to @phuclv for solving my cmd Issue

Comment: please take a 1-minute [tour] to understand how this site works. Please don't post thank-you comments, instead [accept and/or up vote useful answers that help you](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: [How can I restore Cmd.exe (Command Prompt) if it doesn't exist?](https://superuser.com/q/1635048/241386)

Answer (score 0):

**All** Windows from Vista and up include PowerShell (in the forms of a console and a separate Integrated Scripting Environment). You can look for PowerShell from the start menu, or open Windows Explorer and search for **`powershell.exe`**. There should be quite a few results in *System32* and in *WinSxS*. If it's not available then you can search for **`powershell_ise.exe`** for Powershell ISE (Integrated Scripting Environment)

In 64-bit Windows there should also be a 32-bit `cmd.exe` in C:\Windows\SysWOW64. Similarly there will also be the 32-bit versions of PowerShell and PowerShell ISE in that folder

As a last resort you may try to run `conhost.exe` which is the real console in Windows that's used by other terminal applications like cmd.exe or powershell.exe

Nevertheless depending on what you want to run, **you may not need a console at all**. Executables can be run directly from the address bar of Windows Explorer, task manager or the **Run dialog**. Only internal commands of `cmd.exe` need to be run from inside cmd.exe. But all of those have an alternative version in PowerShell

Or you can simply download a 3<sup>rd</sup> party terminal application, since you have internet access

That said, once cmd.exe went missing, **some serious issues had happened** and you should reinstall or fix Windows, because normally if any system files were deleted or has a different signature, [SFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_File_Checker) will automatically kick in and restore the file. You can also force a recheck/restoration by running `sfc /scannow`. Again sfc can be run from run dialog or explorer's address bar without a console